# trouble with the AJAX GET function

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, request

I have been looking around the internet for examples of an AJAX function which gets the latest messages from a database, I have been playing around with the code but I am stuck, currently I don't know how I get the data from the php file to a variable in JQuery. sounds confusing maybe looking at my code will help.

any help is much appreciated.

**JQuery code**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", url: "include/process.php", 
    data:{
       getLatestActivity: "true",
       toUser: "4"
    },
    success: function(data){
       alert("data: "+data);                   
    }
});
```

**php processing request**

```
function getLatestActivity(){
   global $session;

   $data = $session->getLatestActivity(mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['toUser']));

   if($data){//successful
      return $data;
   }
}
```

The data function only prints out "data:", Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to pass data from PHP to Javascript you need to `echo` a string/json representation of what ever data you are trying to return. Note: `echo json_encode($data);`

```
function getLatestActivity(){
   global $session;

   $data = $session->getLatestActivity(mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['toUser']));

   if($data){//successful
      echo json_encode($data);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is more code than this, but if not your actually running the PHP file when calling it with Ajax, and you will have to run the function aswell:

```
function getLatestActivity(){
   global $session;

   $data = $session->getLatestActivity(mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['toUser']));

   if($data){//successful
      return $data;
   }
}

$mydata = getLatestActivity();
echo $mydata;
```

If it's the only function you could just remove the function call and run the code directly, and depending on the format of the data you may have to decode it like the other  answers are saying.